# Expression is always false

Tags: c#

Here is a problem which I encountered today.

I have a statement in C#

```
 EmPayRollData emPayRollData = payroll.EmPayRollDatas.First();
```

Both payroll and EmPayRollData are entities. i.e. payroll is the parent and EmPayRollData is the child.

Now I have a statement:

```
companyRow.CompanyName = (empowerPayRollData == null) ? string.Empty : empowerPayRollData.Name;
```

I get a resharper comment saying: "Expression is always false"

Comment: I think you need to revise your code sample.  I think one of your entities is misspelled and it took me a minute to figure out where payroll was.  It's unclear exactly what you're doing.  Can you post the contiguous code block that's exhibiting issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `payroll.EmPayRollDatas` may be empty, you should instead use:

```
payroll.EmPayRollDatas.FirstOrDefault()
```

which will return null in the case of an empty enumerable. `First` would throw an exception in this case, so if the line of code you are questioning were reached, the sequence is therefore not empty and your variable cannot be null.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks to you and everybody else.

Answer (score 5):

That is because `First()` will either return an object or throw an exception if it can't. Resharper knows that if you get to that line, then empowerPayRollData won't be null. You might consider using `FirstOrDefault` in this case.

Comment: Nice, I completely missed that!

Comment: Resharper is impressive, I must say :)

Answer (score 1):

Resharper probably knows that `.First()` will result in non-null or an exception.

From that it can be inferred that the expression will always be false.

If you expect empty result-sets, use `.FirstOrDefault()`